# How to implement class 'categories' in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Suppose I have different sort of products on my site, so I have classes like Restaurant, Hotel, Trip, Attraction. Each type of product / services has its own class because they have different fields and some specific methods.

How could I categorize this different classes? Like for example categorizing all Trips and Attractions as 'Activities'. Do I need to create a superclass for this, even if they have very little logic in common? Or maybe use a class variable '@@category' ?

My main need is to be able to query all instances of the classes belonging to specific categories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is assuming these products can only belong to one category, and all products belong to the same category.

Create a new model (and table) Category.

Create whichever categories you need (let's say "Activities" and "Locations").

Create a new table product_categories, with fields model (string) and category_id (integer).

Create the seed data for product categories - something like model: Trip, category_id: 1

Voila, your trips are now an activity. I suggest adding a scope to find by category_id, maybe a belongs_to association with custom join SQL.

Answer (score 1):

If there are behavioral or field changes, consider [STI (single-table inheritance)](http://code.alexreisner.com/articles/single-table-inheritance-in-rails.html).

If there's a "large" number of fields that are different, I'd consider just hanging stuff off the main model.

Comment: There are not really any behavorial or field changes, I just need the categories to filter contents. What do you mean with hanging stuff off the main model? What would the main model be?

Comment: @oalo I misunderstood the question; I thought you were asking how to make a class hierarchy from them, not just have a single category per type. Although I'd still consider it if they're similar.